# Reacting to a key pressed on a DataGridView new row, but not creating a row for it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where, if the user presses a key in the new row, I want to open an other window which knows about which key was pressed, but not to create the new row. I have seen that `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events  are ignored here; I can use `RowsAdded`, but the row gets added; or I can use `CellBeginEdit` and set `e.Cancel=true`, but then I can't access the pressed key. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyPress` event is indeed what you want.

It is not ignored by the `DataGridView`, but it is handled by the `TextBox` that takes care of the user input.

So you need to catch it there.

Here is an example:

```
TextBox editTB = null;   // a class level variable to hold the reference

// here we get the reference to the editing control
// other control types will work as well..
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is TextBox) 
    {
        editTB = (TextBox)e.Control;
        editTB.KeyPress -= editTB_KeyPress;
        editTB.KeyPress += editTB_KeyPress;
    }
}

void editTB_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // use the checks you actually need..
    if (e.KeyChar == '#')
    {
        // do your things..
        Console.WriteLine("---->" + e.KeyChar);
        e.Handled = true;   // eat up the key event
    }            
}
```